# how do I write a class which allows instances to be introspected upon with __name__?

Tags: python, introspection

Writing a class Foo which allows its instances to return the names they were created with using `__name__`,

```
A = Foo(args)

str(A.__name__)
```

should return 'A'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not possible (at least, not in all cases and not without dirty tricks). In your example, `A` is a reference to an object of type `Foo`. The object has no knowledge of how references to it are stored. If you write:

```
A = Foo(args)
B = A
```

then `A` and `B` both reference the same object, and are totally indistinguishable, so you couldn't find which one was used to hold the first reference to the object. Of course, you could scan `globals()` for references to the object, and you would then find `A` and `B`. However, if you `del A`, all traces of `A` will have vanished.

What are you trying to do? If you explained the use case, maybe we could suggest an alternative solution than what you asked.

Comment: Some objects don't even have *any* name - `mylist.append(Foo(args))` just tacks an object onto the end of mylist, with no name of its own at all.